# Mirror site attack

Tags: web-browser, domain

I've created and published a `.com` web-application (nodejs-express in backend, react in frontend) with social-login (facebook, google, linkedin etc..). But I haven't gone out publicly to ask people to use it, just a few beta-testers.

Today I when I googled the name of the site just to see if I could find it as a search result, I realized that a mirror with the `.me` domain came up first, and that led to the webpage. But it had not https, so I had to click "advanced -> proceed anyways" in chrome.

What are they trying to do, is it common with such attacks? Are they usually automated or made manually? And what can I do to stop it? Perhaps crash the site if it's not https or on the correct path?

```
if(location.origin !== 'mydomain.com' || location.protocol !== 'https:'){
document.body.innerText = ''
}
```

Comment: That JavaScript idea won't work against anyone even slightly competent, as they'll just change/remove it in their copy.

Comment: There is nothing known about your site  and of the behavior of the mirror so it is unclear what "they" intend to do by mirroring it. If you would specify the exact domain names one could have a closer look. But with this current lack of information any answer would be pure speculation which makes the question too broad.

Comment: @JosephSible I obfuscate the code, is possible somehow to use some tricks to change global variable name etc? Or is it worth at all to spend time to solve it that way, since they can always change the source..

Comment: @user1506145 IMO it's not worth it at all.

Comment: @user1506145: *"...  I just wanted to see if __such things__ are common ..."* -  unfortunately your question does not provide enough details of what *"such things"* actually is. Also, you specifically ask for way more than just if this is common and to answer all this we actually need the missing details.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I see what you mean, the thing is I would like to not have the domain name searchable or in the "edit history". Is it ok with my previous comment with the domain or do you want me to edit the original question? Is it possible to remove the actual domain names after you have taken a look or I've gotten an answer? 

Or is there any other closed forum or chat you can recommend where I can ask the question?

I found this site, perhaps I should just report it here: https://safebrowsing.google.com/safebrowsing/report_phish/?hl=en

Comment: @user1506145: any edits (like add the name and remove it later) are visible in the edit history. This is a public site here and as far as I know there are no really private conversations here possible. The intend is actually to have the information public so that everybody can profit from it. Given that I still don't know enough about the original and mirror I cannot do any recommendations regarding reporting it to Google Safebrowsing.

Comment: @user1506145: This was essential information because it shows that there is likely no attack at all. `myserials.me` simply points to the same IP address as your domain. This IP address is hosted by DigitalOcean. Likely the owner of `myserials.me` had this domain once hosted at DigitalOcean and later abandoned it without removing the DNS records.

Comment: @user1506145: To make it more clear: there is no mirroring done at all. It is simply that both domains resolve to the same IP address and thus end up at the same server - your server at DigitalOcean. And since the certificate is only valid for your domain any HTTPS access using the other domain name results in a certificate warning - details will then show that the certificate is issued for your domain (as expected since it is your server).

Comment: @SteffenUllrich What a relief, thank you so much! Apologies for my faulty assumptions. This will let me sleep better tonight :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101146/discussion-between-user1506145-and-steffen-ullrich).